# Same request parameter several times results in a comma seperated string?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

When passing the same request parameter in a URL several times:

```
mypage?lang=en&lang=co&lang=he
```

When looking on the server side, it seems that it's translated to a comma seperated string:

```
string Lang = Request.Params["lang"];
// Lang = "en,co,he"
```

Is this normal behaviour? Is there any server side setting or a proper coding way to eliminate this behaviour and get only the first value and dismiss all other parameters? By dismissing, I mean "clean" all other URL parameters from the query string (I find this cannot be done so easily).

Comment: This is normal behaviour, yes. If you only want the first one then just ignore the rest, or throw an exception to tell the client they've done something silly.

Comment: @DavidG The thing is that I'm the silly one creating this situation, but cannot find where. In the meantime, I want to solve this ASAP by clearing the URL from the duplicate params

Comment: It's quite easy write some simple code to get only the first value of a comma delimited string. Will that help?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thanks neshama, getting the first value of a comma delimited string is easy, but I need to clear the URL from the duplicate request parameters.

Comment: You can't change the URL that has been passed in, at least not in a simple way. Cope with it or fix the code that is creating it.

Comment: How do you generate the URL to begin with? Do you have control over that process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are certain that you will always want to use the first param and use `en` then you can do this as well

```
var langParams =  Request.Params["lang"].Split(
                  new string[] {","},
                  StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
```

**This will return en**

Answer (score 1):

This is a normal behaviour, because param keys must be unique.
When you put multiple params with the same key, instead of throwing an exception, returns an array. You should use only :

```
 var langParams =  Request.Params["lang"].Split(',');
 if(langParams.Length > 0
 {
     var firstlangParam = langParams[0];
     //do your staff....
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, getting the first value of a comma delimited string is easy, but I need to clear the URL from the duplicate request parameters

Comment: Do you want to clear the URL ? Can you post the code which create the URL please ?